# InfoPath table calculated column: simplifying conditional statements

Tags: infopath, calculated-column, conditional

I have a table in SharePoint using InfoPath where I would like to have a Calculated column with a conditional formula based on the values of another column.  I have a formula that works:

```
=IF(OR(MyField="Thing", MyField="Something Else", MyField="Another Thing"}),"Something","Nothing")
```

But I would like to use an array (as I have in an Excel workbook for a similar table) to look something like this:

```
=IF(OR(MyField={"Thing","Something Else","Another Thing"}),"Something","Nothing")
```

Is there a way to simplify the first formula so that I don’t have to write out `MyField = 'for each item'`?

In my real case, there are 10 items in `MyField` that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it the hard way

```
=IF(OR(MyField="1",MyField="2",MyField="3",MyField="4",MyField="5",MyField="6",MyField="7",MyField="8",MyField="9",MyField="10"),"Something","Nothing")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are very sure those 10 values are unique you can do it with a String comparison:

```
=IF( 
      ISNUMBER(
                FIND(
                     "Six"
                     ,"OneTwoThreeFourFiveSixSevenEightNineTen"
                    )
              )
      , "Something"
      , "Nothing"
   )
```